# WebEngineView: Set custom font to html content

Tags: qt, qml

How to apply custom font (font is in qrc) to some part of html content in `WebEngineView`?

Comment: Since that is `*View` you cannot edit content, only viewing. Or, as a workaround you can get page html code, change it and set it by calling `WebEngineView.loadHtml()`

Comment: HTML content loaded with `WebEngineView.loadHtml()`. I can use custom font from QML like this: `TextArea { font.family: "myFont" }`. And it's working. The problem is how to use this font from HTML content using CSS in WebEngineView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to use my custom font (but I'm not sure how safe is this):

1. Add custom font to qrc: `://res/font/myfont.ttf`;
2. Create `style.css` in qrc with this content:

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: myfont;
     src: url('qrc:/res/font/myfont.ttf');
     font-weight: bold;
   }

   body {
       font-family: 'myfont';
       text-align: justify;
       line-height: 25px;
   }
   ```
3. In QML when content loaded to `WebEngineView` add your `style.css` to HTML:

   ```
   WebEngineView {
       id: webEngineView
       onLoadingChanged: {
           if (loadRequest.status == WebEngineView.LoadSucceededStatus) {
           webEngineView.runJavaScript(
               "var headHTML = document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;" +
               "headHTML += '<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"qrc:/css/styles.css\">';" + 
               "document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML;"
               );
           }                
       }
   }
   ```
4. And last, run your app with this command line argument `--disable-web-security`